# Base64 Decode doesn't work with accent charaters

Tags: javascript, unicode, encoding, base64

I'm using the logic in http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript_base64.html#.Wqn0dB2WbCI to decode a string encoded in base64. Decoding works fine for all alphanumeric characters except for accent characters like è. The unicode for è is 232.
Would be great if somebody can explain the problem.
The code I've used is as follows:

```
function decode(input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3;
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;
        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");
    _keyStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

        while (i < input.length) {

            enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
            }

            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }
        }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Let me introduce you to [`atob` / `btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)

Comment: A better-known source: [Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#The_Unicode_Problem) maintained by the major browser vendors.

Comment: Used MDN version and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: base64 operates on binary bytes, not on text characters. Javascript strings are Unicode. If you are decoding something that represents text, you have to first decode the base64 to bytes, then decode the bytes to a string using the charset that the bytes represent. If you don't know what that charset is, you are SOL for non 7bit ASCII characters. When encoding a string to base64, you have to first encode the string to bytes using a chosen charset, then encode the resulting bytes to base64.